# Facebook search with and without access_token

Tags: java, facebook, search, access-token

I did this research (without access_token):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q="il padrino"&type=page&fields=id,name

Among results I see the first one:

"id": "104130852958000",
"name": "Il padrino"

which is the most important page for "il padrino", as you can see when you search manually on Facebook.

Then I did this research (with an access_token with every permission):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22il%20padrino%22&type=page&fields=id,name&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Among results someone disappeared and also the one before with id:104130852958000!!!

I tried this strange behavior with other strings different from "il padrino", but in many cases there is the same problem (or viceversa: some results disappear without the access_token).

How is it possible? How can I get a complete list of results?

Actually I think I have to join the research with and without access_token... but it seems strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's annoying.  Please log it as a bug with Facebook:  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and post a link to your report here too so others who find your question can see it's current bug.

Comment: ACK. Facebook response time is pretty good. But then it takes a while until they fix it ;-) Usually it's better to go straight for a workaround. After reporting, of course.

Comment: Thanks, please accept this answer since it is a bug.  That way other people who find this question will know that the answer is that it is a current bug.

Comment: @DMCS, Better to wait for it to be assigned/prioritized/confirmed by Facebook developers on a bug tool before saing it's a bug...

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. You cannot rely on what is being returned since it may and probably will. Trying to predict search results is just wrong, the results may (and really do) differ between users, geographical locations, content restrictions and probably other things too.

BTW, I'm not getting the page you speak about no matter using `access_token` or not.

Comment: Ok, I'm not trying to predict results, but I'd really like a complete list of them! This "indeterminism" is annoying... That is: if you want to search for the page in italian language with the maximum numer of Like for the movie "Il padrino" (that is The Godfather) it is id:104130852958000! And you said you cannot get it from your point with or without access_token... I think it's a strong missing!

Comment: I'm not getting it in first page of results, there is a paging. Complete list of results may be huge, I didn't tryied to receive all of 'em. The results just can't be the same for all users, even if result set is the same it will be ordered by some kind of relevance...

Comment: If I add the parameter &limit=5000 to avoid the paging I got a lot of results but the problem persist...